# Mongoose promise in foreach failed in my case

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How to do promise with forEach? I want to get all jobs, but get the data of applicants. My Job schema already have the applicant id, but how to query the user and merge their detail in the output?

```
Job.find({}).then(result => {

  result.forEach(obj =>{
    const applicant_id = obj.applicant._id
    if(applicant_id){
        User.findOne({_id: applicant_id})
        .then(user=>{
          return res.json({
            status: 1,
            data: {
              ...obj,
              applicant: {
                ...user
              }
            }
          })
        })
    }
  })

}).catch(err => {
  if(err){
    return res.status(400).send({
      msg: err
    })
  }
})
```

I tried Promise but I'm stuck merging user into the Job obj,

```
Job.find({}).then(result => {

  let promiseArray = []
  result.forEach(obj =>{
    const applicant_id = obj.applicant._id
    if(applicant_id){
      promiseArray.push(
        User.findOne({_id: applicant_id}))
    }
  })

  return Promise.all(promiseArray)

}).then(user => {

  console.log(user)
  //this work but this is only the user's data, 
  //I need it to be within obj which is Job data

})
```

Comment: You need [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: @ChrisG tried that but I stuck.

Comment: @ChrisG yeah, did that!

Comment: You want to map jobs and users together? E.g each obj has its own user? Because that response looks fishy.

Comment: @Zlatko no it's not, how can it be fishy? isn't that every car is a owner?

Comment: Well, it looks totally weird. You have a `data` object, which is a hashmap - of spreaded array of jobs, so it would mean something like '0', '1', '2' as keys and jobs as values. And then one more, last key is `'applicant'`, which again is a spread of user array. Totally looks weird.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to filter items in result to exclude those without applicant id, then map this array to array of promises, and finally pass it to `Promise.all`. This should do it:

```
Job.find({}).then(result => {
  const promises = result
    .filter(obj => obj.applicant._id)
    .map(obj => {
      const applicant_id = obj.applicant._id

      return User.findOne({ _id: applicant_id })
        .then(user => {
          return res.json({
            status: 1,
            data: {
              ...obj,
              applicant: {
                ...user
              }
            }
          })
        })
    })

  return Promise.all(promises)
}).catch(err => {
  if (err) {
    return res.status(400).send({
      msg: err
    })
  }
})
```

Comment: You need to chain another `.then()` to `Job` and call `res.send(...)` in there (right before `.catch`)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tested and working solution:

```
Job.find({ applicant: { $ne: null } }).populate('applicant').then(result => {
    res.send(result);
}).catch(err => {
    return res.status(400).send({
        msg: err
    })
});
```

Comment: doesn't work, data is only showing user result, not Job data.

Comment: You can avoid JSON.parse/stringify if you User.find().lean();

Comment: @Zlatko Good point, but I've since removed the previous "solutions" ;)

Comment: woah what is this? Hmm, no looping anymore? let me try it out

Comment: @JennyMok yeah, the looping happens internally thanks to the `populate` function. It's basically what `JOIN` does for SQL-type databases.